# How to Play Both Video and Audio from the Same Video File Using Python (moviepy and pygame)?

Tags: python, audio, video, pygame, moviepy

I am working on a Python application that needs to play both video and audio from the same video file using the moviepy and pygame libraries. I have tried the following code, but it only plays the video, and the audio is not audible:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
import pygame
import sys

# Initialize pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the dimensions of the screen
screen_width = 640
screen_height = 480

# Create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

# Load the video file
video_file = 'your_video.mp4'
clip = VideoFileClip(video_file)

# Get the video's frames per second (FPS)
fps = clip.fps

# Create a clock to control the frame rate
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Play the video
playing = True

def toggle_play():
    nonlocal playing
    playing = not playing

pygame.display.set_caption("Video Player (Press Space to Toggle Play/Pause)")

# Main game loop
frame_idx = 0
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                toggle_play()

    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    if playing:
        # Read the frame at the current time
        frame = clip.get_frame(frame_idx / fps)
        frame_idx += 1
    else:
        frame = clip.get_frame(frame_idx / fps)

    if frame_idx >= int(clip.fps * clip.duration):
        frame_idx = 0

    # Convert the MoviePy frame to a format suitable for pygame
    frame_surface = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(frame.swapaxes(0, 1))

    # Display the frame on the screen
    screen.blit(frame_surface, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)

# Clean up and quit
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

I would like to achieve synchronized video and audio playback from the same source file. How can I modify the code or use these libraries to achieve this?

Specifically, I want to:

Load a video file and play its video frames using moviepy.
Simultaneously play the associated audio from the same video file.
Be able to pause and play both video and audio using user input.
Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!